# How to rename entity extraction labels in Google Auto ML Natural Language Entity Extraction?

Tags: google-cloud-automl, named-entity-extraction

In Google Auto ML Natural Language Entity Extraction, when hovering over a label, it presents the options, "Rename or remove item", but upon actually clicking the settings, I am only given the option to delete the label. I have made a spelling mistake on one of the labels.

[Rename and remove item option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF6Ct.png)

[Only presented with option to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ35b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as well in my project and is presented with the same scenario you encountered.

For Classification and Entity Analysis, you can add a new label  with the new/correct name, then assign all the items to the new label from the old label, as a workaround. [1](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/datasets#label-items)

Unfortunately, this is not available as an option for Entity Extraction. Before training your custom model, you need to annotate the training documents in the dataset. You can annotate training documents before importing them [2](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#expandable-2), or you can add annotations in the AutoML Natural Language UI.

You could try to file an issue for this to be investigated internally. [3](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) Just select Create new Cloud Natural Language API issue for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will submit an issue and hope this issue gets addressed.